# PHP Variable on Form Submission

Tags: php

I'm building a form that passes a value to Concrete5, i'm almost there as I have been able to get one value across, put not the other, which uses the typeahead.js.

The code is straightforward, however as im a novice php developer I cannot seem to get it working. I need the value from the input box into $school. The full_name is the correct method of doing this and works completely fine, but I cannot seem to implement it for the school using an input box which is needed

```
   <div>
 <?php $full_name = 'akID[' . UserAttributeKey::getByHandle('full_name')->getAttributeKeyID() . '][value]'; ?>
        <?php echo $form->label($full_name, t('Full Name')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->text($full_name); ?>
   </div>
   <br/>

<div class="center-block" id="form">
<?php $school = 'akID[' . UserAttributeKey::getByHandle('school')->getAttributeKeyID() . '][value]; ?>]'; ?>
   <?php echo $form->label($school, t('Please Select your School from the Dropdown Box.') )?><br/>

     <form id="schoolForm" class="form-signin" role="form" method="post">
    <input type=text id="<?php echo $school; ?>" name="<?php echo $school; ?>" class="form-control typeahead" placeholder="Enter Your School "> 
     </form>

</div>
```

Comment: The PHP script executes on the server, and the HTML form is rendered in the browser. There are just a few ways to get information from the browser to the server. One way is to post the form to a PHP script on the server. Another appropriate method in this case is XHR.

Comment: I know it's confusing when you see PHP script and HTML mixed in the same file. Thing is, the PHP and HTML don't work at the same time. The process starts on the server, so the PHP does it's job. At this time the HTML is simply text. Then PHP sends text (HTML in this case) to the browser and the browser renders it to display a form. At this point, there's NO PHP, and no direct connection to PHP execution.

Comment: Thanks for the information, any ideas on how I go about it? I dont get how the full name was 2 lines of code and the other seems like a pain in the .. to get working

Comment: Wild guess. Maybe, in the form, `name="<?php echo $school; ?>"` ought to be simply `name="school"`.

Comment: @bloodyKnuckles haha, it was last ditch desperation, ive tried many different forms